# automapper - flattening list properties to individual single properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a destination class, which look like this:

```
public class CustomerAddressSummary
{   
    public string StateTxt { get; set; }

    public string AddrLn1 { get; set; }
    public string AddrLn2 { get; set; }

    public string Phn { get; set; }
    public string HomePhnNbr { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhnNbr { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhnNbr { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddr { get; set; }
}
```

And the source class:

```
public class CustomerAddressSummaryObj
{
    public ADDRESS Address { get; set; }
    public List<COMMUNICATION> Communications { get; set; }        
    public string StateTxt { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
CreateMap<CustomerAddressSummaryObj, CustomerAddressSummary>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StateTxt, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StateTxt))  
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AddrLn1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.ADDRLN1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AddrLn2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.ADDRLN2));

CreateMap<COMMUNICATION, CustomerAddressSummary>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Phn,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Main ? src.DETAILS : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailAddr,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Email ? src.DETAILS : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HomePhnNbr,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Home ? src.DETAILS : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MobilePhnNbr,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Mobile ? src.DETAILS : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WorkPhnNbr,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Work ? src.DETAILS : null));
```

Implementation:

```
var customerAddress = _mapper.Map<CustomerAddressSummary>(customerAddressSummaryObj);
```

This is populating all information except `COMMUNICATION`. So I tried something like this:

```
var customerAddress = _mapper.Map<CustomerAddressSummary>(customerAddressSummaryObj)
    .Map(customerAddressSummaryObj.Communications,_mapper);

public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(this TDestination destination, TSource source, IMapper mapper)
{
    return source == null ? destination : mapper.Map(source, destination);
}
```

But, this is also not working and throwing an exception. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve using `Linq`

```
CreateMap<CustomerAddressSummaryObj, CustomerAddressSummary>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailAddr, opt => opt.MapFrom((src,dest) => src.Communications
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TYPECD == Constant.CommunicationTypeCode.Email)?.DETAILS))
```